# Active transient voltage suppression clamp parts/design

Tags: tvs, over-voltage-protection

I am revising a design that was originally specified with a SMBJ54CA [2] bi-directional TVS protection diode in front of an LM76202-Q1 [3]; this is in conformance with the design example in section 9.2.2.5.1 of the LM76202-Q1 datasheet in the positive direction. (Application requirements for reverse voltage are different, hence the use of a bi-directional TVS instead of an assymetric reverse TVS.)

The SMBJ54CA has a breakdown voltage range of 60.0 V - 66.3 V at 25°C, which is already a bit marginal -- the LM76202-Q1 has an absolute maximum rating of 65V. Unfortunately, concerns have been raised over the temperature variation of the TVS, which is about 0.1%/°C. Because the working voltage of the application is up to nearly 60V, going to a lower-breakdown-voltage TVS (to keep the maximum breakdown voltage <= 65V at maximum temperature of 85°C) is not an option.

TI has an article [4] on high-temperature TVS usage where they (of course) recommend their own alternative, the "flat-clamp" part family [5], which basically uses active control of a MOSFET to simulate a TVS:

[image: Figure 6 from reference 5]

From their material, this has a cost in terms of response time, but has significant advantages in terms of breakdown accuracy (at 25°C) and stability over temperature.

Unfortunately, they don't have a 60 V part for this, and while using a 27 V part and a 33 V part in series is a possibility, that wouldn't be my first choice.

So, questions:

- Is anyone aware of equivalent parts (TVS-diode-style across-the-rails voltage clamps) that may fit the requirements here?
- Does anyone have experience doing this with discrete parts (and in particular achieving the desired fast response)?
- Am I asking the right questions?

---

[2] https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smbj_datasheet.pdf.pdf

[3] http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm76202-q1.pdf

[4] http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva930/slva930.pdf

[5] http://www.ti.com/lit/wp/slyy127/slyy127.pdf

Comment: What surge current are you trying to protect against? And please don't tell me you are trying to protect against over-voltages and not surge currents.

Comment: DO-160G section 17 category A -- so 600 V @ 50 ohm source for 2 us / 8 us (12A peak) -- and section 22 level 3 set B -- so shorter transients to 300 A.

Comment: Given the max working voltage being so high I don't think you'll find a TVS to do the job of protecting the LM76202.

Comment: Seems a hard problem to me: Application 60V and protection 65V. There‘s only 5V headroom. What‘s your application temp. range exactly?

Comment: In the past I've engineered a fast series open-circuit circuit but this disengaged the circuit so, for a period of time the device didn't operate. There's also the possibility of using an emitter follower regulator but, of course there will be losses. Alternatively, use a high voltage buck regulator with low forward drop OR a buck-booster.

Comment: -40°C to 70°C board ambient continuous; -55°C to 85°C short term. Yeah, the 5V headroom is exactly the problem -- this was much easier when the working voltage was spec'd at 48V instead of 60V. I'd rather fix this at the overvoltage protection side because frankly the LM76202 has treated us well; the alternative is to get some more headroom by going to an LTC4364 instead, but (other than Vin(max)) it's overkill and much more complex for this application.